# How do I plant cocoa beans?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've got two cocoa beans and would love to plant them, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot plant cocoa beans in Minecraft versions below 1.3.1. As the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cocoa_Bean) says, they can only be used as dyes and to make cookies and they can only be found in chests in dungeons.

As of 1.3.1, you can plant cocoa beans on the side of jungle trees to grow [cocoa plants](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cocoa_Plant), from which you can harvest more cocoa beans.

Answer (score 6):

As of the 1.3.1 release cocoa beans may be "planted" on the trunks of jungle trees.  There they become a green pod that turns orange as it grows.  When harvested the mature pods release several beans.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, cocoa beans are not plant-able, they are only used to make brown wool and cookies.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong: [murgatroid99's answer is the correct one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/48659/3389). Can you please delete it?

Comment: You are forgiven for posting an answer that was correct at the time of posting, but yeah, things have changed in the past 6 months.

Comment: This answer should not be deleted, nor should it be down voted. It is well written, succint, and was correct at post. It can be edited, if op chooses to.  The correct answer should instead be upvoted.  Mark, on the other hand, please consider deleting your comment.